# Data validation matching with a list with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a certain range of cells in excel where I want to apply data validation on another data validation.

I want the user to only have 3 options for data input within range of cells:

1. either a number,
2. a range of numbers or by
3. choosing from a dropdown list that contains words and numbers.

I already implemented number 1 and 2 with the following function:

```
Function checkStr(ByVal str As String) As String

    Dim objRegEx As Object, allMatches As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With objRegEx
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "^\d+(-\d+)?$"
    End With


    Set allMatches = objRegEx.Execute(str)
    checkStr = (allMatches.Count > 0)

End Function
```

Since the above function will only allow numbers or a range of numbers to be inputted, any ideas on how to add a validation to allow values from a pre-defined list containing both words and numbers?

Comment: Why is the function returning String and not Boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to change the return `As Boolean` and then just filter the `str` against an array of valid list entries.

```
Function checkStr(ByVal str As String) As Boolean

    Dim objRegEx As Object, allMatches As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With objRegEx
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "^\d+(-\d+)?$"
    End With

    Set allMatches = objRegEx.Execute(str)


    Dim ValidList As Variant
    ValidList = Array("123", "456") 'your list of valid entries

    'check if either str is in the ValidList OR matches the regex
    If (UBound(Filter(ValidList, str)) > -1) Or (allMatches.Count > 0) Then
        checkStr = True
    End If

End Function
```

If the list of valid entries is in a range you can replace it with:

```
ValidList = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("SheetName").Range("A1:A10").Value)
```

Comment: Sorry if this may be a stupid comment but I'm not that knowledgeable in VBA. While copiling, an error is showing saying "compile error: Sub or Function not defined". I'm calling the function with the following code:   If checkStr(Target.Value) = False Then
            Target.Value = ""
        End If

Comment: Is your `Function checkStr` in a module or in a worksheet? Try to make it a `Public Function`. Otherwise in which line does this error occur? If you use the list in a range there was a `s` missing in `Worksheets("SheetName")` it must be `Worksheets` not `Worksheet` (just corrected it) by bad.

Comment: Making it a public function doesn't show any errors, however the code is not working. It's allowing values outside of the defined range and pattern. Updated the code too.

Comment: @TryStudent Well, it worked when I tested it. Can you give an example? What value did you use for `str` and what for `ValidList`?

Comment: For str used the value "test" while for validList used "VBA"

Comment: @TryStudent Well, it says `False` for running `Debug.Print checkStr("test")` where `ValidList = Array("VBA")`

Comment: Copy pasted the same code into a new document and it worked. Thanks for your help really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

The list is taking values from some range. Thus, take the range of the list and use the `Application.Match()` to check whether the `str` is there:

```
Public Function checkStr(str As String) As Boolean

    Dim isItError As Variant
    isItError = Application.Match(str, Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A5"), 0)

    checkStr = Not IsError(isItError)

End Function
```

`Application.Match()` would return either `error` or `true`. Thus, your function can be fixed with `Not IsError()`.

---

And if you want to compare Strings with Strings and Numbers as Numbers, try to pass the variable as Variant and let VBA decide what it is actually:

```
Public Function checkMe(someVar As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim isItError As Variant
    Dim formulaAddress As String

    With Range("C1").Validation
        formulaAddress = Right(.Formula1, Len(.Formula1) - 1)
    End With

    isItError = Application.Match(someVar, Range(formulaAddress))
    checkMe = Not IsError(isItError)

End Function
```

If you explicitly define the variable as a numeric or string, the other option would be excluded in the `Application.Match()` comparison:

```
?Application.Match("1",Array(1,2,3))
Error 2042
?Application.Match(1,Array(1,2,3))
1 
?Application.Match("1",Array("1","2","3"))
1 
?Application.Match(1,Array("1","2","3"))
Error 2042
```